# Html2canvas only rendering parts of element visible in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I have an element that doesn't have a set width or height that I'm taking a screenshot of. It's being pushed into local storage to be used as a background image in the next page. The problem is that if the document is zoomed in on, so is the image or if part of the element is cut off it only shows the visible part in the image. I figure the solution would be to set the width and height based on document size, but I'm not sure how to implement that because there's not a lot of documentation or threads on this.

The function for the capture is shown below:

```
function oncap() {

var crt = "none";
var canv = document.getElementById("allcontainer");
html2canvas(canv).then(function(canvas) {
    window.localStorage.clear;
    localStorage.setItem(canvasName, canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
    window.location.href = 'FLOWCANVASTEST.html';

}); 
}
```

Edit: The solution ended up being on the display side rather than the capture itself. When I was pulling the image from local storage I was setting it as a background image; setting background-size to contain resolved the zooming issue for anyone else that gets this kinda thing.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is before you draw your canvas you can read the size of the screen and then pass that to the canvas when it draw the image so your canvas init would look something like this:

```
initCanvas: function () {
            canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-man');
            c = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.width = document.getClientWidth;
            canvas.height = document.getClientHeight;
            return canvas;
        },
```

Then you could pass the height and width to a put image function aswell

```
putImage: function (x,y) {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.onload = function () {
                c.drawImage(img, 0, 0, x, y);
            }
            img.src = 'images/products.jpg';
            img.id = 'canvasImage';
    }
```